# Rails: Add a before_action to a Devise generated admin controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have made an admin model with Devise. But I don't want the `/admins/sign_up` to be accessible to anyone but the Admin (since I don't want anyone to sign up to be an admin). Will a good solution be to create a `before_action :authenticate_admin!` in the admins_controller? If so, how can I do this (since the controller isn't in the controller folder by default)? Or is there a better practise to do this?

Comment: best option is two create a user controller (basically if u are using devise , you have to overwrite the function ) and in that use before_action :authenticate_admin! functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using devise only for the admins, you might want to remove the `:registerable` option from the model. That way no one can 'register' to be an admin, only you have the power to create new admin via the console.